# Magento2 import product csv permission denied error

Tags: magento2

Why am i getting this warning all of a sudden!

```
var/importexport/catalog_product.csv" cannot be deleted Warning!unlink
```

during the product csv import

I have full write permission for var folder

Comment: Please check youy .csv file may be "repeated attribute are placed or attributes are not created in backend " It is not a permission issue

Answer (score 0):

Ok got the issue...Issue was i had missed out one Attribute Set in the backend, But dont know why the error dint specify this!